# Is there a safe way to use a non-public method as a signal handler?

Tags: php

I am implementing a pre-fork tcp socket server in PHP, working with multiple child processes, shared memory, semaphores, and various signals.

I am currently using protected methods for my signal handlers.

Unfortunately, this occasionally fails with "cannot access protected method" errors.

I am pretty sure that this happens when the signal is delivered while the code is in a method in some other class (the shared memory class, for example).

I would prefer to use protected methods because these methods really shouldn't be called from any other user land code.

My question is: Is there any safe way to use non-public methods as signal handlers?

Comment: I would advice you to include some code into your question. It will increase the chances of getting an answer and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** No. It is not safe to use a non-public method as a signal handler.

**Longer answer (why):**
Although I am no PHP internals expert, I have written a number of custom PHP extensions over the years and have some familiarity with the internals so I decided to research this question by looking at the actual PHP functions involved.

User land signal handlers are not actually called by the operating system.

The *pcntl_signal()* function adds a structure representing the user land signal handler to an internal list and then (through some other calls), sets up the *pcntl_signal_handler()* internal function as the actual handler for the specified signal.

When the signal is delivered, the operating system calls *pcntl_signal_handler()*  which modifies the internal signal handler table and sets the global *pending_signals* flag to one.  If asynchronous signals are enabled it also sets the global *vm_interrupt* flag to one.

At some point after that, PHP will call the internal version of *pcntl_signal_dispatch()* which does some sanity checking and house keeping and eventually calls the *call_user_function()* internal function.

As far as I can tell, *call_user_function()* is used whenever a user land callable is to be called from within PHP (well, *call_user_function()* is actually a macro that *calls _call_user_function_ex()*).

The *_call_user_function_ex()* function sets up a structure and then calls *zend_call_function()*.

z*end_call_function()* eventually calls *zend_is_callable_ex()* which makes a number of checks to see if the user land function is callable, including the current scope, and that check fails if the signal is delivered while the application is executing in any scope other than the class in which the signal handler was delivered (a user land database abstraction method or logger, for example).

So no, it is not safe to use a non-public method as a signal handler.